# Excel formula to find the longest string separated by characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have lots of strings separated by pipes in a column in Excel. None of the strings separated by pipes are allowed to be longer than 15 characters, so I want to find out if any cells have a string separated by pipes of more than 15 characters.

So in the example below, let's say that that is A2,A3,and A4. The formula will be in column B. the Formula in the B4 should alert me that A4 breaks the rule.

```
Bobby|Janet
Ted|Sammy|Susan|Fred
Billy|Maddie|JohnJacobJingleheimerShmitt|Matthew
```

Ideally, this formula should give me the actual number of characters in the longest string.

(Perhaps I need to create a custom formula with VBA?)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Open to VBA solution?

Comment: With VBA, almost trivial. Without VBA, much harder.

Comment: I was afraid someone would ask that . . . I'm sorry to say that at this point I'm befuddled, so I don't have anything. I didn't know VBA could be used to create custom formulas until now. That looks really promising.

Comment: I did do a ton of Googling though. Other Stack Overflow questions about finding the length of string between two particular characters had only two of those characters per cell. With this situation, I have an undetermined number of strings and characters, so those wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel then use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"|",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"|",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))>15,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"|",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"|",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)) & " has " & LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"|",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"|",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))) & " Characters.",""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

With out Office 365 we can return a canned return but not the actual length

```
=IF(OR(LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))>15),"This cell has an entry with too many Characters","")
```

This is still an array formula, it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: My comment above should have read "With VBA, almost trivial. Without VBA, much harder (unless your name is Scott Craner)."

Comment: @JohnColeman I keep waiting for Microsoft to release those new formula to us that cannot be beta tester due to work constraints.  I am soooo looking forward to see what I can do with `Filter()` and the others.

Comment: I agree. It is surprising how much Excel has improved in some ways but how little in others. Built-in functions now are not all that much better than in 2000 (I am still using Excel 2016, so can't even use `Textjoin`).

Comment: Wow. That was fast. You guys are awesome. I actually tried it on Excel Online but it didn't work. I guess I'll have to do it on my other computer later with full Excel on it.

Comment: @DarrenJansen Excel Online does not allow array formulas.

Comment: Hello @ScottCraner, this is next level stuff you do! One remark, OP ideally would like to see the max number returned. So maybe include that into your option; e.g.: `{=MAX(LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))))}`, maybe even replace the iftrue statement with this :). So you CAN return the actual length :)

Comment: @ScottCraner I see. I'll try it again with my other computer.

Comment: @JvdV that works if only one is greater than the 15, if more than one then it will only display the max, where as the TEXTJOIN will display all that are over.

Comment: Anyone care to explain what the rept is doing here in and why?

Comment: @urdearboy It is adding 99 spaces where the `|` is,  It allows for a large landing pad for the mid to find.  The array of starting positions will always land in the spaces.  Then we trim the excess spaces.

Comment: I know @scottcraner, but it's actually OP's wish to show this: ' 'Ideally, this formula should give me the actual number of characters in the longest string'

Comment: Then yes you can put that in the true return of the second formula and it will return the longest length of string. @JvdV

Comment: This worked! Thank you for opening up a whole new level of Excel.

Both of these worked on my desktop Excel.

They also worked on Google Sheets for what it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

*If you are open to VBA Solution...*

```
Option Explicit

Public Function LenTest(Target As Range) As String

Dim Temp: Temp = Split(Target, "|")
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(Temp) To UBound(Temp)
    If Len(Temp(i)) > 15 Then
        LenTest = "Fail @ " & Temp(i)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i

LenTest = "Pass"

End Function
```

---

To implement, `Open VBE > Insert Module > Paste Code`

Then you can just call the function from your worksheet like any other function and select the cell that you want to test like so: `=LenTest(A1)` which will return `Pass` or `Fail @` with the string that fails (I.E. char length > 15)

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 2013+ (and not Excel for MAC), you can use the `FILTERXML` function to split the string on the pipe into an array of results.

Then use the `LEN` function to get the length of each element
Finally use either `AGGREGATE` normally entered to return the length of the longest, or use the `MAX` function in an array formula for the same result.

```
=AGGREGATE(14,4,LEN(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")),1)

=MAX(LEN(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")))
```

*(To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.)*

[image]